# $\mathbf{X}\in N(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Lambda})$ Find the conditional distribution $P(X_{1},X_{2}|X_{3}=x)$

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability

Let $\mathbf{X}\in N(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Lambda})$
Find the conditional distribution $P(X_{1},X_{2}|X_{3}=x)$
 \begin{equation*}
     \begin{split}
        \mathbf{\Lambda}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
            v_{11} & v_{12} &v_{13} \\
             v_{21} & v_{22} &v_{23}\\
             v_{31} & v_{32} & v_{33}
        \end{array}\right)
     \end{split}
 \end{equation*}
  From Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions
  \begin{equation*}
      \begin{split}
          \mathbf{x_{1}}, \mathbf{x_{2}}\\
                \mathbf{x}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
                     \mathbf{x_{1}}  \\
                     \mathbf{x_{2}} 
                \end{array}\right]\quad \text{with sizes}\quad \left[\begin{array}{c}
                     q\times 1  \\
                     (N-q)\times 1
                \end{array}\right]\\
                \mathbf{\mu}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
                     \mathbf{\mu_{1}}  \\
                     \mathbf{\mu_{2}}
                \end{array}\right]\quad \text{with sizes} \quad \left[\begin{array}{c}
                     q\times 1  \\
                     (N-q)\times 1 
                \end{array}\right]\\
                \mathbf{\Sigma}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
                    \mathbf{\Sigma_{11}} &\mathbf{\Sigma_{12}}  \\
                    \mathbf{\Sigma_{21}} & \mathbf{\Sigma_{22}}
                \end{array}\right]\quad \text{with sizes}\quad \left[\begin{array}{cc}
                   q\times q  &  q\times (N-q)\\
                    (N-q)\times q & (N-q)\times(N-q)
                \end{array}\right]\\
            \end{split}
        \end{equation*}
        \begin{equation*}
        \begin{split}
 \mathbf{\mu}=\mu_{1}+\Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}\left(a-\mu_{2}\right)\\
 \mathbf{\Sigma}=\Sigma_{11}-\Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}\Sigma_{21}
        \end{split}
    \end{equation*}
        In this case $N=3$ and $q=2$. I partition $\Lambda$. 
        \begin{equation*}
        \begin{split}
           \mathbf{\Lambda}=\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}
        v_{11} & v_{12} &v_{13} \\
         v_{21} & v_{22} &v_{23}\\
         \hline
         v_{31} & v_{32} & v_{33}
    \end{array}\right) 
        \end{split}
    \end{equation*}
        \begin{equation*}
        \begin{split}
            \Sigma_{11}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
                v_{11} & v_{12} \\
               v_{21}  & v_{22}
            \end{array}\right]\\
            \Sigma_{12}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
                 v_{13}  \\
                 v_{23} 
            \end{array}\right]\\
            \Sigma_{21}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
              v_{31}   &  v_{32}
            \end{array}\right]\\
            \Sigma_{22}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
                 v_{33}
            \end{array}\right]\\
            \Sigma_{22}^{-1}=\frac{1}{v_{33}}\left[\begin{array}{c}
                 v_{33}
            \end{array}\right]
        \end{split}
    \end{equation*}
        \begin{equation*}
        \begin{split}
            \mathbf{\mu}=\mu_{1}+\frac{1}{v_{33}}\left[\begin{array}{c}
                 v_{13}  \\
                 v_{23} 
            \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
                 v_{33}
            \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
                 x-\mu_{3}
            \end{array}\right]\\
 \mathbf{\Sigma}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
                v_{11} & v_{12} \\
               v_{21}  & v_{22}
            \end{array}\right]-\frac{1}{v_{33}}\left[\begin{array}{c}
                 v_{13}  \\
                 v_{23} 
            \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
                 v_{33}
            \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}
              v_{31}   &  v_{32}
            \end{array}\right]
        \end{split}
    \end{equation*}
        The matrix multiplication in the last two expressions are $2\times 1\cdot 1\times 1$ and I cannot evaluate this.Where did I go wrong in trying to find the distribution $P(X_{1},X_{2}|X_{3}=x)$?

Comment: Why can’t you evaluate a $2 \times 1 \cdot 1 \times 1$ multiplication? The dimensions match up, right?

Comment: But it isn't  $m\times n\cdot n\times p$ then? Both $n,p=1$. You mean the answer to 
                    [ v_{13}  \\
                     v_{23} 
                ][v_{33}]=[v_{13}*v_{33}\\v_{23}*v_{33}]?

Comment: Yes, I’m talking about that multiplication. It’s okay to have $n=p$, we just need the number of columns in the first matrix to equal the number of rows in the second.